# Close Activity when back button press in Dialog Fragment

Tags: android-dialogfragment, onbackpressed

I need to close (finish) the current Activity when back-pressed in Dialog Fragment. Before I used the below code and it worked. But now `onBackPressed` is deprecated.

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return object : Dialog(activity!!, theme) {
        override fun onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed()
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to migrate `onBackPressed` and implemented `onBackPressedDispatcher` as below, but `handleOnBackPressed` is not calling.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    val backPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // code snippet for close Activity
        }
    }

   requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, backPressedCallback)
}
```

How can I modify this code to close Activity when back-press in Dialog Fragment?